# How to start quartz Scheduler by second 0 on Spring?

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I have quartz scheduler jobs. When I start the application, quartz bean starts at that moment. Below code is my spring context. I try to start quartz manager bean by second 0. How can I do? Thank you.

```
<bean name="managerJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="com.abc.cde.quartz.QuartzManagerBean" />
</bean>

<bean id="cronJobManagerSimpleTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="managerJob" />
    <property name="repeatInterval" value="60000" />
</bean>

<bean id="cronSchedulerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="cronJobManagerSimpleTrigger" />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="quartzProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount">25</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean you want to start the job immediately?

Class SimpleTriggerBean

```
void    setStartDelay(long startDelay)
//Set the delay before starting the job for the first time.
```

if i get you, so you can try with property

```
<property name="startDelay" value="0" />
```

If you want to set at specific time:

```
SimpleTrigger.setStartTime(java.util.Date)//Current date with specific time, you might need a Calendar for help
```

Hope that help!

Comment: No, i set start delay 0 while adding job to scheduler. I mean i start application 08:30:15 and quartz manager start at that time. And i set interval 60000. And i see logs at HH:MM:15. But i want to add job scheduler at 08:31:00.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But i didn't express myself well. Quartz running all the time. I have some working hours for quartz and if the running quartz isn't between these hours, it returns. First start of application determine the starting time and quartz puts 60 seconds each time. For example: 20:30:18, 20:31:18, 20:32:18 etc. I try to run each quartz time like 20:31:00, 20:32:00, 20:33:00, etc

Comment: actually, you just need to use current date time in setStartTime, set HOUR,MINUTE and SECOND whatever you want. I suggest about Calendar will help you to do it.